# Detecting that a button's function is completed

Tags: java, if-statement, jbutton, actionlistener, points

I placed an actionListener on some JButtons I created. It is such that if the user clicks a button, another class is called-up. I want to detect if that class has finished its function... for more clarity, here is my code:

```
Quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent iq) {

        JButton source = (JButton) iq.getSource();

             if (point.equals(points.get(0))){

         q1 = new Quest1();  //class called up
         source.setEnabled(false);

         //This is where my problem lies.... I want to be able to detect when the button's action is finished...than some other action takes place!
}
});
```

please help me.....

Comment: That is it!... people downvote without reasoning!

Comment: People downvote because your question is actually not very precise; almost  very close to "unclear what you are asking". Please understand: you should see *any* downvote or close request as **feedback** to you about the quality of your input.

Comment: Are you wanting this action to detect whether there are other actions registered on the button, and wait until all of them have completed?

Comment: "I've applied your code... still not working as desired!" Then post a [mcve] with expected results, instead of expecting mind-reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already wrote the code to that!

You see, unless you put in **extra** effort, a method that calls another method (like in this case: using new to construct another object) does things **in sequence**!

Meaning: your last line with the comment in your listener is reached **after** all other things in your method happened!

The only thing to be aware of: if the constructor of *Quest* would be creating and starting another *Thread*, then of course, things would be different. Then you would need hand-crafted communication between the threads involved. But I am somehow guessing that this is not the case here.

Comment: This is the correct answer... Unless you're spinning up another thread somewhere, the method will be done on the next line.

Comment: Exactly!!.... I'm calling up another class somewhere... and I want to detect if that class has finished executing, then something else takes place!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you starting another thread or aren't you? Instantiating another class doesn't inherently run on another thread. As far as the code you've provided, everything runs top to bottom.

Comment: @Presh_K7 See, and that part is totally unclear in your question. **You** own that code; so you should understand what that constructor is doing! And you are really wondering why people downvote you for such input?

Answer (score 1):

Change a `boolean completed` to `true` then check for that.

Comment: Sorry: if he is not doing multithreading, that is totally useless; and when he is doing multi-threading, things might be much more difficult. So in any case; your answer doesnt help much. As a rule of thumb: answers that make up only a single sentence **never** make up a good answer.

Comment: Why doesn't he just put the code he needs to run in the event. I assume he wants to check if it has ever completed or is not currently running

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call a method there?

```
Quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent iq) {
    JButton source = (JButton) iq.getSource();
    if (point.equals(points.get(0))){
      q1 = new Quest1();  //class called up
      source.setEnabled(false);
    }
    onButtonActionDone()
});

private void onButtonActionDone() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it detect if the button's action has been completed!

Comment: Ah, ok. Just moved `onButtonActionDone()` to reflect that.

Comment: You could have it change a boolean value and check for that change

Comment: This is like saying.... I click a button, a class somewhere is called up! when that class is done with all its action (such that it is disposed or exits)... then do this (another action)....! I've applied your code... still not working as desired!

Comment: "another class is called-up" is a really ambiguous statement and you should clarify what you mean with it in the question.